# Ldap - Can't 'log in' but can ldapsearch - (Log) transport endpoint not connected

Tags: centos, authentication, ldap

I have this problem:
I'm on centos 7 I tryed to set ldap remote credentials access by this:

```
[192.168.9.105 #] authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth 
--ldapserver=ldap://192.168.9.104 --ldapbasedn="dc=myco,dc=local" 
--enablemkhomedir --update
```

launching this query (on the same host I run authconfig on) i get:

```
[192.168.9.105 #] ldapsearch -x uid=ldaprptest -b dc=myco,dc=local -h 192.168.9.104
```

I got the result:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=myco,dc=local> wlocalh scope subtree
# filter: uid=ldaprptest
# requesting: ALL
#

# ldaprptest, People, myco.local
dn: uid=ldaprptest,ou=People,dc=myco,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: ldaprptest
uid: ldaprptest
uidNumber: 9988
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/ldaprptest
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: LDAP Replication Test User
userPassword:: e2NyeXB0fXg=
shadowLastChange: 17058
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

so I'm sure it can connect

after trying

```
su ldaprptest
```

I `[192.168.9.105 #] cat /var/log/messages` and I get:

```
Mar 11 20:02:57 Centos-client-test-slave nslcd[3313]: 
    [d062c2] <passwd="ldaprptest"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://192.168.9.103: 
    Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected

Mar 11 20:02:57 Centos-client-test-slave nslcd[3313]: 
    [d062c2] <passwd="ldaprptest"> no available LDAP server found: 
    Can't contact LDAP server: Transport endpoint is not connected

Mar 11 20:02:57 Centos-client-test-slave rsyslogd: 
    imjournal: rename() failed for new path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state': 
    Permission denied [v8.24.0-34.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

EDIT:
look at logs: it seemps it try to connect to 192.168.9.103 even though I set it up to go 192.168.9.104

also:
What does it mean *transport endpoint is not connected*?

EDIT2
my `/etc/nslcd.conf` is this:

```
uid nslcd
gid ldap
uri ldap://192.168.9.104
base "dc=myco,dc=local"
ssl no
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the nslcd service?

Comment: I rebooted the whole machine, is it the same?

Comment: In the sense that nslcd will have also been restarted along with everything else, it is, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Check the configuration written by `authconfig`; since the log messages are about nslcd, try `cat /etc/nslcd.conf` to make sure it has the correct contents.

To make sure that the correct configuration is picked up, run nslcd in debug mode. You'll have to stop both the `nslcd` and `nscd` services – I think centos uses systemd, so `systemctl stop nslcd` and `systemctl stop nscd` – and run `nslcd -d`.

*Transport endpoint not connected* just means that no network connection was established. In this case, the reason appears to be the misconfiguration.

Comment: question edited: required file added

Comment: ... but have you run nslcd in debug mode?